# Errors after "forever server.js"

Tags: towerjs, forever

I'm using for the first time Tower.js and I'm following the README.md instructions. When I try to start the server with the "forever server.js" command, hereby the result:

> $ forever server.js
>
> info: socket.io started
>   Tower development server listening on port 3000
>   TypeError: Object Mac OS X 10.8.2 has no method 'match'
>       at Object.Tower.MiddlewareAgent [as handle] (…)/node_modules/tower/lib/tower-middleware/server/agent.js:13:21)
>       at next (…)/node_modules/tower/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:199:15)
>       at Object.handle (…)/app/config/server/bootstrap.coffee:23:14)
>       at next (…)/node_modules/tower/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:199:15)
>       at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (…)/node_modules/tower/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/methodOverride.js:37:5)
>       at next (…)/node_modules/tower/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:199:15)
>       at multipart (…)/node_modules/tower/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:64:37)
>       at module.exports (…)/node_modules/tower/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:57:9)
>       at urlencoded (…)/node_modules/tower/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/urlencoded.js:51:37)
>       at module.exports (…)/node_modules/tower/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:55:7)
>   127.0.0.1 - - [Sat, 12 Jan 2013 18:10:11 GMT] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 1718 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/536.26.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.2 Safari/536.26.17"

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An issue has already been set two days ago https://github.com/viatropos/tower/issues/375.

Seems fixed and the pull request #376 has [just been merged](https://github.com/viatropos/tower/commit/a6a6bd9fa9d83d9b7311ec3c7e2c58b7f94c8d1f) (5 hours ago).

Next build should be good.

Comment: I don't think so. I use this repo version and the Travis build failed: https://travis-ci.org/viatropos/tower

But thank you for the link!

Comment: @SebastienThiebaud The travis build is failing because of a few tests. We haven't gotten around to fix them yet.